# Are combinations and permutations stable in Scala collections?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Should I rely on the order of combinations and permutations generated by corresponding methods of Scala's collections? For example:

```
scala> Seq(1, 2, 3).combinations(2).foreach(println)
List(1, 2)
List(1, 3)
List(2, 3)
```

Can I be sure that I will get my results always in the same precise order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the documentation does not says anything on the order. It just says:

> An Iterator which traverses the possible n-element combinations of
>   this sequence.

So it doesn't guarantee. 
Ideally you should always get the order as you printed but it is not guaranteed by the library. So its (pessimistic) safe not to trust it and rather do sort it so that you get the same series always:

```
scala> import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._

scala> Seq(1,2,3).combinations(2).toList.sorted.foreach(println)
List(1, 2)
List(1, 3)
List(2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the bad news :) 
Sorting those could be problematic, because both have a tendency to be very big on reasonably sized collections.

Answer (score 1):

The `combinations` implementation maintains the order of the elements in the given sequence.

Except that input is processed to group repeated elements together.

The output is *not* sorted.

```
 scala> Seq(3,2,1).combinations(2).toList
 res1: List[Seq[Int]] = List(List(3, 2), List(3, 1), List(2, 1))
```

The sequence is updated to keep repeated elements together. For instance:

```
 scala> Seq(2,1,3,1,2).combinations(2).toList
 res2: List[Seq[Int]] = List(List(2, 2), List(2, 1), List(2, 3), List(1, 1), List(1, 3))
```

in this case seq is first converted to Seq(2,2,1,1,3):

```
 scala> Seq(2,2,1,1,3).combinations(2).toList
 res3: List[Seq[Int]] = List(List(2, 2), List(2, 1), List(2, 3), List(1, 1), List(1, 3))

 scala> res2 == res3
 res4: Boolean = true
```

Comment: It's good you've mentioned that peculiarity regarding repeated elements, as I didn't know that.